# Select in Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Well, I did some research before posting here and I haven't find the correct solution.

Here is my SQL, I would like to improve the performance and remove select clause after where if possible by join or any other way.

The catch is Table1 is the first table to join and it is the same table in Where clause. I am not sure whether I am doing it right or wrong. I would like to know if there is any other efficient way to get the same result

```
SELECT T3.Id, T3.Name 
FROM dbo.Table1 T1 
JOIN dbo.Table2 T2 ON T1.Id = T2.Id
JOIN dbo.Table3 T3 ON T2.Name = T3.Name
WHERE T1.fId = (SELECT fId FROM dbo.Table1 WHERE Id = 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a simple join:

```
SELECT T3.Id, T3.Name 
FROM dbo.Table1 T1 
inner JOIN dbo.Table2 T2 ON T1.Id = T2.Id
inner JOIN dbo.Table3 T3 ON T2.Name = T3.Name
inner join dbo.Table1 T4 on T4.fId  = T1.fId and T4.Id= 1
```

Comment: Not getting the same result

Comment: @Chatra if it worked. [Accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a `WHERE` clause in the subquery with a fixed value, you can simply replace the whole query by the value used

```
SELECT T3.Id, T3.Name FROM dbo.Table1 T1 
JOIN dbo.Table2 T2 ON T1.Id = T2.Id
JOIN dbo.Table3 T3 ON T2.Name = T3.Name
WHERE T1.Id = 1
```

Comment: T1.fId is not 1, fId from table1 where Id = 1 is fid

Comment: It was a mistake. i Fix it

Comment: Where do you I need to use IN

Comment: @Hadi If subquery returned more than 1 result, then OP should get error with `=` operator.

Comment: In your query provided in question, ` WhERE T1.fid IN (SELECT ...)`

Comment: @OtoShavadze you're right, i removed the note from my answer

Answer (score 0):

See if you want output of only T3 table then use "Exists" clause

```
SELECT T3.Id, T3.Name 
FROM dbo.Table3 T3
where exists(
select t2.id from  dbo.Table2 T2 
inner join dbo.Table1 T1 on T1.Id = T2.Id
where T2.Name = T3.Name
and t1. Id = 1
)
```